# Android - ViewPager third tab has not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-viewpager

i have a viewPager that contains 3 tabs fragments.
the first and the second fragments works fine but when i sweep to the third tab
i do not see him.
the third tab has shown only when the activity with the viewPager has reload(move to another activity and return).

my code:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), Constants.TAB_0);
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), Constants.TAB_1);
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), Constants.TAB_2);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}
```

pager adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
/*
 * Arraylist used to contain the fragments
 * and contain fragments title's
 */
private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

//Adds the fragment and it's title. Called in MainActivity
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

//Retrieves the title of the tab
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

}

Comment: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is my adapter, on getItem I set the fragment object to the Fragment activity.

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Fragment fragment;

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 0){
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
        }

        else if (position == 1){
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        }

        else if (position == 2){
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "name one";
            case 1:
                return "name two";
            case 2:
                return "name three";
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Then in my main activity I call it like so:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
SectionPagerAdapter sectionPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(sectionPagerAdapter);


TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Try replacing your code with above and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**USE** `new PagerAdapter(getChildSupportFragmentManager());`**instead of** `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Try this one !!